# Copy Paste Icon in JTextPanel

Tags: java, swing, icons, copy-paste, jtextpane

I am doing a chat program with Javaswing and I would like to insert smileys in a JtextPanel and be able to select them for copy paste (in the same panel).

[image]

I'm doing that at this moment :

```
Icon iconSmiley = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ola/smileys/smiley-angel.png"));
        this.messageTextArea.insertIcon(iconSmiley);
```

but it's not working

somebody has any idea ?

Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean "select them for copy paste" ? You should first define what you're going to do when pasting the mix text/image into a text input area, a graphic canvas, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this?
http://java-sl.com/tip_autoreplace_smiles.html